# MySQL Calculate Percentage from one table

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, hibernate

I need to calculate percentage for top 20 failed users, Need it in spring java with hibernate.

```
+--------------+--------+------------+
| id  | result | code  |  techUser_id
+--------------+--------+------------+
| 1   | fail   | 23442 |  2
| 2   | fail   | 56432 |  5
| 3   | fail   | 98745 |  2
| 4   | fail   | 65478 |  5
| 5   | fail   | 36448 |  2
| 6   | fail   | 87745 |  5
+--------------+--------+------------+
```

Expected output: list of top 20 failed with max % of total number of records by per user

I am not sure about Query what it should be, so please help me to find the solution.

something i have, I know its not correct :--

```
select techUser_id, count( * ),(SELECT COUNT( * )  from inspection) * 100 ,
count( * )/(SELECT COUNT( * )  from inspection) * 100 as perc
 from inspection
 where techUser_id != ''
 and inspectionResult ='FAIL'
 group by techUser_id
 order by  perc limit 20;
```

and getting this result

[image]

Thanks

execute this query for a check

```
select techUser_id, result, count(*) num
from inspection 
group by techUser_id, result
order by num
```

[image]

Comment: Precentage of what? in you data i don't see the value for calculate the percentage

Comment: total number of records by per user

Comment: total number of records   per user OK ... but respect to ? total number of records in table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 select techUser_id, count(*),(SELECT COUNT(*)  from inspection) * 100 ,   count(*)/(SELECT COUNT(*)  from inspection) * 100 as perc 
 from inspection 
 where techUser.id != '' 
 and result ='FAIL' 
 group by techUser_id 
 order perc limit 20;
```

execute this query for a check

```
select techUser_id, result, count(*) num
from inspection 
group by techUser_id, result
order by num
```

Comment: I am getting this error :- You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order perc limit 20' at line 6

Comment: what is i use something like that:- select techUser_id,  count(*)/(SELECT COUNT(*)  from inspection) * 100 as perc
 from inspection
 where techUser_id != ''
 and inspectionResult ='FAIL'
 group by techUser_id
 order by perc desc limit 20;

Comment: @krishan  in the code in comment you have count() this is wrong you must use count(*) this mean all the count (related to group by condition).. for the code with order by 1 you mean order by techUser.id  .. so you obtain the first 20 User by id and not by percentage ..

Comment: right, thanks for that,   group by techUser_id order by perc desc limit 20;

Comment: I have update the answer so the result contain also the values for calculation .. show me the worng result please and the reason because are wrong

Comment: I just update question with result i am getting with your query

Comment: I have update teh answer with a simpel quety for chek .. show the result of this query too. (a part of the result)

Comment: added image from 2nd query

Comment: The second query show that for  the techUser_id and rinspectionRsut  fail you have only 1 row.. so..the result of the first is right . Could be you need the calcultion on other values

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT techUser_id, COUNT(*) AS Total , (COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM inspection WHERE result='fail')) * 100 AS 'list of top 20 failed with max', 
FROM inspection
WHERE result='fail'
GROUP BY techUser_id;
```